# Spline Interpolation in R

Tags: r, spline

I have some data with

```
h = c[157 144  80 106 124  46 207 188 190 208 143 170 162 178 155 163 162 149 135 160 149 147 133 146 126 120 151  74 122 145 160 155 173 126 172  93]
```

Then I get local maxima with diff function

```
max = [1  5  7 10 12 14 16 20 24 27 31 33 35 36]
```

I have simple matlab code to find spline interpolation

```
maxenv = spline(max,h(max),1:N);
```

This code will show result

```
maxenv = 157    86.5643152828762    67.5352696350679    84.9885891697257    124 169.645228239041    207 224.396380746179    223.191793341491    208 185.421032390413    170 172.173624690130    178 172.759468849065    163 158.147870987344    157.874968589889    159.414581897490    160 157.622863516083    153.308219179638    148.839465253375    146 146.051320982064    148.167322961480    151 153.474200222188    155.606188003845    157.685081783579    160 163.653263154551    173 186.027639098700    172 93
```

Now I'm trying with R but got some errors

```
maxenv <- spline(max, h(max), seq(N))
```

Then error

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: The error speaks for itself. `max` and `h(max)` are of differing lengths. Read `?spline`.

Comment: What are you using, Matlab or R?

Answer (score 0):

You're code and question are really not clear, so I'm not 100% sure this is what you are looking for:

```
# vector of values

h <- c(157, 144, 80, 106, 124, 46, 207, 188, 190, 208, 143, 170, 162, 178, 155, 
       163, 162, 149, 135, 160, 149, 147, 133, 146, 126, 120, 151, 74, 122, 145,
       160, 155, 173, 126, 172, 93)

# local maxima
lmax <- h[c(1, which(diff(sign(diff(h)))==-2)+1, length(h))]

# spline calculation
spl <- spline(1:length(lmax), lmax)

# visual inspection
plot(spl)
lines(spl)
```

[image]